# Extending SVGGElement using Polymer

Tags: svg, polymer, web-component, custom-element

I am trying to create a custom element that extends a SVGGlement. Here is the JSBin link to the code: http://jsbin.com/kovumoloda/2/edit?html,console,output

When I run the code, ready() isn't called and so aren't the contents of the Shadow DOM rendered.

I tried the same example without Polymer and it worked. Here is the JS Bin link http://jsbin.com/vihosojofi/1/edit?html,console,output

Is there anything I need to do differently to make this thing work with Polymer ?

Thanks !

Comment: A quick search of the [Polymer issue tracker](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/search?q=svg&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) suggests that SVG isn't well supported (which partly relates to the Web Components spec being HTML-centric, but if the native implementations are working fine it really is a Polymer bug).  You might want to go through those issue reports to see if any cover your problem, else file a new report.